# How to show More button for timeGrid in fullcallendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullCallendar for my schedules and I have a lot of events in time (container) and it doesn't look good. So I am trying hide unnecessary events and show More + N button.  I found dayMaxEventRows option but it worked only when view type month and when week view not worked.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
headerToolbar: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
},
dayMaxEventRows: 2,
events: [
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00", "end":"2020-09-01T08:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2020-09-01T07:00:00+00:00"},
],
```

});

When month view type it worked:

[image]

[image]

And when week view type not working:
[image]

How can I show More button in fullcallendar?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/0gqutLrd/30/)

Comment: The documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover) is quite clear that this feature only works either in "month" view, or for "all-day" events in the timeGrid view. It never claims to work in the situation you're describing. Frankly, having that many events which all start at the exact same time on the same day is probably a bit unlikely for most situations. Is this a realistic prospect for your calendar?

Comment: @ADyson, in practic it is so realistic for my calendar. I have a schedule for interview conferency and in one time will be writed more the 10 interlocutors. Do you know how to do it? Just I'm trying write own code for this now, maybe you have any ideas.

Comment: You would have to change the source code of fullCalendar to make it work.

Comment: P.S. Why don't you just put one single event in the calendar for the interview, and then put the names of everyone attending into the description? Then you could make a popover which occurs when you hover or click on the event, which would have space to show all the names. The effect would be similar, but a) it's more logical that one real-life meeting has one event in the calendar, and b) it's easily possible without messing about with the fullCalendar code.

Comment: Ok, thank you for you idea! It is realy more logical then my. But it have one propblem: I can not dragging the interlocutor name from event description to another event.

Comment: You can probably make individual bits of the HTML draggable with some code of your own, I guess. Or think of a different GUI design for transferring people - is it a very frequent task which needs to be super-easy with dragging, or could it be done via a form or something, if it's not used very often.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you! I think of you idea.